# How to customize streamlit expander widget

Tags: html, css, streamlit

From reading the documentation of streamlit components I know that it is not possible to render html code for label parameter of the `st.expander()` function.

Is there a workaround?

What I want to do exactly is this:

```py
from annotated_text import annotation

with st.expander(
        markdown(context[:start_idx] + str(
        annotation("**" + answer + "**", "ANSWER", "#ff0074")) 
        + context[end_idx:])):
    
        #some code
```

So far, I will get something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mh I think `st.expand` has really hard restrictions to its label (not even colored markdown is possible afaik) and this is not possible. Maybe it would be easiest to have something like

```py
from annotated_text import annotation

annotate( <your text rendered with annotated_text>)
with st.expand("Learn more:"):
    # some more code
```

So the text you want to have annotated is just above the label.

If you just want some parts of the label highlighted, using simple markdown would be easiest:

```py
with st.expand("This text is _cursiv_, and this is __bold__."):
    # some more code
```